# Assign random unique string to few UIButton in swift

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn4: UIButton!


    var btnList: [UIButton]!
    var stringList: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btnList = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
        stringList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

        randomString()

    }

    func randomString() {
        for btn in btnList {
            btn.setTitle(stringList.randomElement(), for: .normal)
        }
    }

}
```

Results at UIButton have same String apply on Button Title. How to assign unique and don't repeat the used string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve that is like following:

```
let buttonList = [UIButton(),UIButton(),UIButton(),UIButton()] //say these are the buttons
let titleList = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
var appliedList = [String]()  //this will be use to hold the string we have already seen



func setRandomTitle() {
    for button in buttonList {
        let requiredTitle = getRamdomString()
        debugPrint(requiredTitle)
    }
}


func getRamdomString() -> String {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(titleList.count))) //get the random index
    let requiredTitle = titleList[randomIndex]
    if appliedList.contains(requiredTitle) {
        return getRamdomString()
    }
    appliedList.append(requiredTitle)
    return requiredTitle
}
```

Comment: Thanks kathayatnk. Your useful tips help me a lots. To complete my code.

Comment: Great, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn4: UIButton!


var btnList: [UIButton]!
var stringList: [String]!
var uniqueStringList = [String]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    btnList = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
    stringList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


    randomStringButton()

    print(uniqueStringList)

}

func randomString() {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(stringList!.count)))

    let randomString1 = stringList[randomIndex]

    if uniqueStringList.contains(randomString1) {
        return randomString()
    }

    uniqueStringList.append(randomString1)

}


func randomStringButton() {

    for _ in 1...stringList.count {
        randomString()
    }

    for (index, btnName) in btnList.enumerated() {
        btnName.setTitle(uniqueStringList[index], for: .normal)


    }
}
```

Thanks for everyone share tips. This is working code.